# Download completed envelope document using DocuSign iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, docusignapi

I'm using a [native ios sdk](https://github.com/docusign/native-ios-sdk). I have created an envelope and signed it. For creating and signing the envelope I was using the [documentation](https://github.com/docusign/native-ios-sdk/blob/master/Compose-Envelope.md) and suggestions that were given on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66969169/cannot-create-an-envelope-using-online-signing-mode) topic.

Now, I want to download my signed document. In [Android mobile sdk](https://github.com/docusign/mobile-android-sdk) there is a `DSEnvelopeDelegate` which has a method `downloadCompletedEnvelopeDocument` (description [here](https://docusign.github.io/mobile-android-sdk/index.html?com/docusign/androidsdk/delegates/DSEnvelopeDelegate.html)).

But in iOS SDK I can't find any methods which make the same work.
How to download the completed envelope document using iOS SDK?
In case if it not available in iOS SDK how to do this (maybe use some API etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to download completed envelope using DocuSign iOS SDK

For now, it's best to use the [API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/download-envelope-documents/) to download the envelopes as current iOS-SDK version doesn't support downloading the completed envelopes from server. It's on the roadmap for iOS-SDK to have this functionality after summer (anticipated release Aug 2021). With API, there is an option to [download individual, zip-archive or combined](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/get/) documents of a signed envelope.

Comment: Is it possible to get the completed envelope document from the device in case offline-signing?